# Bulk Insert from table to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, bulkinsert

I am implementing an **A/B/View** scenario, meaning that the **View** points to **table A**, while **table B** is updated, then a switch occurs and the view points to table B while table A is loaded.

The switch occurs daily. There are millions of rows to update and thousands of users looking at the view. I am on SQL Server 2012.

My questions are:

- how do I insert data into a table from another table in the fastest possible way? (within a stored proc)
- Is there any way to use BULK INSERT? Or, is using regular insert/select the fastest way to go?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to use SSIS.

Make table A an OLEDB source and table B an OLEDB destination. You will bypass the transaction log so reduce the load on the DB. The only way (I can think of) to do this using T-SQL is to change the recovery model for your entire database, which is far from ideal because it means no transactions are stored, not just the ones for your transfer.

**Setting up SSIS Transfer**

Create a new project and drag a dataflow task to your design surface

[image: Tool box menu]

Double click on your dataflow task which will take you through to the Data Flow tab. Then drag and drop an OLE DB source from the "Data flow Sources" menu, and an OLE DB destination from the "Data flow Destinations"  menu

[image: Data flow sources][image: Data flow destinations]

Double click on the OLE DB source, set up the connection to your server, choose the table you want to load from and click OK. Drag the green arrow from the OLE DB source to the destination then double click on the destination. Set up your connection manager, destination table name and column mappings and you should be good to go.

**[OLE DB Source docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx)**

**[OLE DB Destination docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx)**

Comment: Yes, the transaction log is a concern. Do you have any examples of how to setup a source table as an OLEDB source? The examples on the web are all about loading from text files... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could to a Select ColA, ColB into DestTable_New From SrcTable. Once DestTable_New is loaded, recreate indexes and constraints.

Then rename DestTable to DestTable_Old and rename DestTable_New to DestTable. Renaming is extremly quick. If something turns out to have gone wrong, you also have a backup of the previous table close by (DestTable_Old).

I did this scenario once where we had to have the system running 24/7 and needed to load tens of millions of rows each day.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the

```
SELECT fieldnames
INTO DestinationTable
FROM SourceTable
```

as a couple answers suggest, that should be as fast as it can get (depending on how many indexes you'd need to recreate, etc).

But I would suggest using **[synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx)** in order to change the pointer from one table to another.  They're very transparent and in my opinion, cleaner than updating the view, or renaming tables.

Comment: For straight `SELECT *` type functionality, synonyms would be more efficient.  They're very useful for cross-database references, too.

Comment: Actually, I may have to stick to views because views provide ALTER functionality where synonyms need to be dropped and re-created.

Comment: This method is not bulk insert and generate a lot of logs

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I was hunting for an answer to the same question and didn't find anything really helpful.  Yes the SSIS approach is a possibility, but the question wanted a stored proc.

To my delight I have discovered (almost) the solution that the original question wanted; you can do it with a CLR SP.

Select the data from TableA into a DataTable and then use the WriteToServer(DataTable dt) method of the SqlBulkCopy class with TableB as the DestinationTableName.

The only slight drawback is that the CLR procedure must use external access in order to use SqlBulkCopy, and does not work with context connection, so you need to fiddle a little bit with permissions and connection strings. But hey! nothing is ever perfect.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT... SELECT...` functions fairly similarly to `BULK INSERT`. You could use SSIS, like @GarethD says, but that might be overly complex if you're just copying rows from table1 to table2.

If you are copying serious quantities of data, keep an eye on the transaction log -- it can bloat up pretty fast when doing huge inserts. One work-around is to "chunkify" the data you are inserting, by looping over an insert statment that processes, say, only 100,000 or 10,000 rows a time (depends on how wide your rows are, i.e. how many MB per pass).

(Just curious, are you doing `ALTER VIEW` to reset the view? I did something similar once, though we had to have four tables and four views to support past/present/next/swap sets.)

Comment: Yes, I am currently doing ALTER VIEW, but I think I am going to switch to using synonyms per Sylvia's suggestion.

Comment: I retract this -- views appear to be a better option because they provide for ALTER functionality where synonyms are limited to drop/create.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but....If you drop and create synonyms within a transaction, it will appear atomic

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```
    select * into A from B Where [criteria]
```

This shall select the data from B, based on the criteria and shall insert it into A, provided the columns are same or you can specify column names instead of *.

Comment: He is asking for 'bulk' not regular load.  The problem with this answer is that it will blow up your transaction log for large transfers.  Doing it in batches using a where loop, CLR, SSIS, or BULK INSERT is preferred and sometimes the only solution.

Comment: @AliRazeghi, please go through the question again, the user has asked for the fastest way to insert data from one table to another table, regardless of simple sql, bulk insert, transaction log maintainability issues.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer but millions of rows in a production system could cause LOTS of locking/blocking based on the isolation level and hardware.  That could take a very long time.  A select * into a from b would be the simplest answer but not the fastest.