# How to use BULK INSERT to move data between two tables?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

How to use BULK INSERT to move data between two tables? I can't find a tutorial with examples. I have 10 mln records to move. SQL Server 2012 SP3. It is one time action. I can't use cmdshell, I can't use SSIS. I have to move data in batches. It is going to be a night job. I say "move" but I don't have to delete records in source. Target table exists already, I don't have to check some constraints and NO foreign keys.

Comment: Please provide some more detail about the question

Comment: I have no examples on how to use bulk insert when I have source table and destination table. I can't use bcp. I have to move about 10 mln rows.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? One time action or automatic multi action? Same server or differen servers? Same network or different? Please provide more details!

Comment: Same server. MS SQL 2012 SP3. Two databases. One time action, but admin has to do it using script.

Comment: Is the target table existing already? Can all data be shifted *as-is* or might be existing data where you get constraint/key violations? One time action or multiple? Please invest some minutes! I think I took more time to ask you for details, that it took you to place your question. You are the one looking for help...

Comment: And: Does *move* mean *delete in source*? 10 mln rows is quite a lot. Is the target system under high pressure or might this be done in one nightly running job?

Comment: Why `BULK INSERT` specifically? Wouldn't you just want to know the fastest way to copy data from one table to another, regardless of method?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11100589/1048425

Comment: I have to use a script, I can't use cmdshell. I can't use SSIS.

Comment: It might be a night job, when db is free off users.

Comment: You did not answer this yet *Is the target table existing already? Can all data be shifted as-is or might be existing data where you get constraint/key violations?* But this is absolutely important!

Comment: Target table exists already, I don't have to check some constraints and NO foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to shift data from one database to another, as long as both are located in the same server (as you wrote it).

As you want to use a script and you want to **copy** records from one table to another you might use this:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.TableName(col1,col2,col3...) 
SELECT col1,col2, col3 ... FROM SourceDB.dbo.TableName
```

This would copy all rows from here to there.

In your question you do not provide enough information, but you want to use a **script**. The above is a script...

- If you have existing data you should read about `MERGE`
- If Target and Soure do not have the same structure, you can easily adapt the `SELECT` to return exactly the set you need to insert
- If you do not need to copy all rows, just add a `WHERE` clause
- If the user you took to connect has not the necessary rights ask the admin. But - from you question or comment - I take, that this will be applied by an admin anyway...
- If the databases live in two different servers, you might read about `linked server`
- And finally you might read about `import and export`, which is widely supported by SSMS...

Comment: Shnugo, I have to migrate 15 mln rows. I have to do it in batches and using script.

Comment: While a *free-of-user-nightly-job* this works in one go... 15 mln is quite a lot but not *out-of-range*... If you need to split this, you can easily use any kind of filter to build appropriate chunks and shift them within a loop. If you need help with this, please start a new question. Try to **ask about the actual problem** and not (only) about the approach you thought would be best. `BULK INSERT` is (probably) not needed at all... Try to avoid the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If **this answer** solves **this question** please accept

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my problem by maybe you are right that it is a XY problem behavior.